# Is it possible for the client to directly connect to an exit node?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, network-configuration

If I'm not mistaken, Tor connections take place like this:

```
Client -> Entry node -> [Multiple middle nodes] -> Exit nodes
```

Is it possible for a client to directly connect to an exit node (deliberately or otherwise), ala VPN?

If so, what are the security implications of this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use Tor as a single-hop proxy.

It was intentionally disabled in [#1751 - Project: Make it harder to use exits as one-hop proxies](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/1751) .

In terms of security, you'd lose all anonymity.

Answer (score -1):

1 Tor Circuits Search 
Website= www.Onionite.now.sh

Search terms include FLAG:Exit Country:

You need to set in TORRC for Tor Browser once you find the fingerprints of the exit nodes you want to use.

StrictNodes 1

ExitNodes exitnodefingerprint, exitnodefingerprint, exitnodefingerprint

For Tor compiled TORRC is configured as such

#StrictNodes 1

#ExitNodes

```
ExitNodes exitnodefingerprint, exitnodefingerprint, exitnodefingerprint
```